# Problema con el uso de Expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

Al utilizar Expanded me da la excepcion : " Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" y

> "RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically,
> Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget.
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
> ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Expanded ← Padding ← Column ← Center ← DecoratedBox ← Padding ←
> Container ← _BodyBuilder ← ⋯`"

Sé que el error se corrije poniendo Expanded por encima de Padding en el siguiente ejemplo

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/fondo_reactions.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 60),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                    ),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 12,
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(SwipeablePageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                MenuSecundario(TiposModos.Test),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Test',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.75),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                    ),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 12,
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(SwipeablePageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                MenuSecundario(TiposModos.Mejorde3),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Mejor de 3',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                    ),
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 12,
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(SwipeablePageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                MenuSecundario(TiposModos.Mejorde5),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Mejor de 5',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          )),);}
```

Pero esque actualmente la vista se ve asi (Y es como la quiero):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si arrreglo el error del Expanded queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y basicamente los parametros de height dentro de los Containers no tienen efecto por lo que no se como conseguir que usando los Expanded donde tienen que estar quede la vista como quiero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede usar `Expanded` por debajo de widgets que no extienden de `Flex` como `Column` , `Row` , etc.

Esto es válido:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
       child: YourChild(
```

Esto no:

```dart
Column(
 children: [
   Padding: ( 
        child: Expanded(
           child: YourChild(
```

El widget parent de `Expanded` siempre tiene que ser uno del tipo `Flex`.

**Updated:**

Para el caso que muestras, no es necesario expanded:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código :

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3796F0),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _MyItem(text: 'Test'),
            _MyItem(text: 'Mejor de 3'),
            _MyItem(text: 'Mejor de 5'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const _MyItem({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 3,
            ),
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, ya lo sabia lo pongo en la pregunta, pero realmente pregunto otra cosa

Comment: ok, déjame hacer un pequeño ejemplo

Comment: osea basicamente si uso expanded , el parametro height de los containers no tiene efecto entonces pasa lo de las fotos

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada, espero te sirva